# Can I read a user's Facebook inbox with a web application?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook4j, facebook-graph-api-v2.4

In the **web application** I'm currently developing, a user should be able to read all the messages from his/her **Facebook inbox**. The corresponding data is supposed to be loaded by the server using [facebook4j](http://facebook4j.org/en/index.html) (Java) and then presented to the user. The current [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4) for the Graph API suggests that the "**read_mailbox**" permission is needed to access the inbox. However, it also says that the use is limited:

> This permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client
>   on platforms where Facebook is not already available. For example,
>   Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In
>   addition, **Web**, Desktop, in-car and TV apps will not be granted this
>   permission.

This indicates that my web application will not even be allowed to use the "read_mailbox" permission when asking the user to grant access. **Did I understand this correctly?** If yes, what kind of app would even be able to use "read_mailbox" based on these stringent limitations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the changelog, the `read_mailbox` permission is deprecated: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_deprecations

...which means, it is not possible at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know of an alternative permission the allows to read a user's inbox, or is this Facebook's way of saying that no other app should be able to access the inbox?

Comment: no, there is no alternative. else it would be mentioned in the changelog.